# Php: can't assign a property value in declaration

Tags: php

I do not understand the rationale behind the different treatment of variable assignment between global context and class context:

```
$var1 = "a" . "b"; # PHP syntax o.k.

class myClass {
    private $var2 = "a" . "b"; # PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';'
}
```

P.S.: visibility of property (private/protected/public) doesn't play a role.

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: This has been asked a million times before, but this question is finally so nice and to the point that I favor it as the canonical question/answer to this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a "variable assignment in class context". `private $var` declares a **property** for the class, and you're additionally giving it a default value. You're *declaring* the structure of the class here, which is not the same as a variable assignment in procedural code. The class structure is parsed by the parser and compiled by the compiler and the default value for the property is established in this *parsing/compilation step*. The compiler does not *execute* any procedural code; it can only handle *constant values*.

As such, you cannot *declare* class properties with default values which need *evaluation*, because the part of PHP that handles the declaration of classes, the parser/compiler, does not *evaluate*.

Comment: Note that *some simple expressions* are slated to be supported in an upcoming version of PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from the PHP [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) (my emphasis)

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this **initialization must be a constant value** -- that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

Instead, define values in the constructor if they're dependent on any evaluation.